# Network Error when doing AJAX GET with jquery inside Visual Studio 2012 web project

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2012, get, xmlhttprequest

I have a simple jquery.ajax call that I'm using to check a user's credentials. My issue is that it works everywhere else (IE8, 9, 10, Chrome, Firefox, VS2008 with IE8) but in my particular case, I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and launching it from there with any browser causes a generic "Network Error".  My call looks exactly like this:

```
var username = $('#Username').val();
    var password = $('#Password').val();
    var qstr = "userName=" + username + "&password=" + password;
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://" + serverId + "/ADService/Service1.asmx/LoginUser",
        data: qstr,
        async: false,
        timeout: 5000,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            alert('Success');
            result = $(xml).find('result').text();
            userId = $(xml).find('userId').text();
            name = $(xml).find('name').text();
            role = $(xml).find('role').text();
        }
    , error: function (xmlHttpRequest, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('response: ' + xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
        alert('status: ' + xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
    }
    }).done(function (data) {
        createCookie("userId", userId);
        createCookie("name", name);
        createCookie("role", role);
        eraseCookie("returningFromPage");

        if (result == "VALID") {
            if (role == "Engineer") {
                window.location.href = "EngrView.aspx";
            }
            else {
                window.location.href = "AD_Select.aspx";
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("Login failed");
        }
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("Login failed (.fail function)");
    });
```

For the configuration I mentioned, this call always ends up in the 'error' event handler with the generic response of "Network Error" and no other information about what happened.

Looking at fiddler, the call actually does go out the server and the response is ok and correct.  I feel like there is some VS2012 setting that I'm not aware of that's killing my call.  Any ideas?